# What is the equivalent to Access' 'SELECT DISTINCTROW * FROM...' in SQLite?

Tags: ms-access, sqlite, distinct

I am converting a DB from Access to SQLite and therefore have to convert/debug all of the sql queries as well. Came across this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW * FROM table WHERE column = value ORDER BY column2;
```

What is the equivalent query using SQLite?

Comment: Is this by chance SQL from an Access app that predates Access 95? In Access 2 and before, SELECT DISTINCTROW was the default for all SELECTs.

Comment: Not sure. It's only in one place in the app that uses the DB. and the DB that I tested with was Access 95. Possibly, though.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: DISTINCTROW is great, and solves many editability problems. But it's certainly non-standard SQL, and should be used only when you need to solve and editability problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE column = value ORDER BY column2;
```

Since there's only one table involved, `DISTINCTROW` acts like `DISTINCT`.

Comment: ...and is likely of no use whatsover in that context. If you have a bunch of records where every single value is identical to the values in another record, then you have bad data, and should question why you have all those duplicate records in a table that you're using DISTINCT. If the table has a primary key, then you should use SELECT with no keyword at all, since SELECT DISTINCT won't return anything different than SELECT by itself would.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Right on the money, there's a possibility of a database design that's perhaps not up to par. Perhaps this transfer from Access to SQLite is part of a cleanup process of the data towards a hopefully better schema?

Comment: Unfortunately for now, no. The main focus of the project is the conversion of the app that uses the DB, but redesigning the DB is not part of plan as of yet. Maybe in the future. Would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent is to ensure that all your tables have keys and that you implement joins and the rest of your query correctly. If you do that then you will never need anything like DISTINCTROW. DISTINCTROW is no more than just a legacy of silliness from Jet.

SELECT * is poor practice. List the columns by name.

```
SELECT column, column1, column2
FROM table
WHERE column = value
ORDER BY column2;
```